# Relationship between arithmetic progression and inversely proportional rule of three.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I did a racing game, where you are a team manager.

In this game, the cars complete laps on several circuits.

I am having trouble reaching a definition in the lap time.

Defining the speed of the car, I also define the time the car will complete the lap.

**So suppose:**

- Car A with speed 10, completes the lap in 60 seconds.
- Car B is 10% slower than car A, so I slow car B by 10% (10 -> 9).
- Car B with speed 9, completes the lap in 66.66667 seconds.
- Car C is 10% slower than car B, so I slow car C by 10% (9 -> 8.1).
- Car C with speed 8.1, completes the lap in 74.07407 seconds.

**Calculated the difference between the cars (C to B and B to A), we obtain:**

- Car C to Car B -> 74.07407 - 66.66667 -> **7.4074**
- Car B to Car A -> 66.66667 - 60 -> **6.66667**

I imagine that the relationship between these two pieces of information is not exactly proportional, but I don't know why.

I would like to know if through the rule of three, it is possible for me to obtain the desired result, feeding the game with speed.

The speed required for the time difference between car C and car B to be the same as the difference between car B and car A is 8.18182.

That is, I need to inform the speed to get the time, and not the other way around.